# Excel Automation not Working after log off from server but works fine when Identity user has logged In

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, pdf, sharepoint-2013

I am using Excel Automation to convert an excel file to PDF. I have used Identity as "This User" and gave credentials of user who has admin privileges. Also I have added the necessary users (IUSRS, Network, everyone, etc) in Launch and  activation, Configuration and access permissions. When I am logged onto server then it Export the excel to PDF Format but when I log off it does not. I am stuck. I know that Microsoft does not recommend to use Excel Automation with Asp.net and also I do not want to opt the third party tool option. I cannot keep a user logged onto server all the time. Please suggest a feasible solution I am stuck in this for long time and it is on high priority. 
Thanks In advance.

Comment: I know you probably don't want to hear this but... Really don't use Excel automation in an ASP project.

Comment: where in your code are you logging the user..? also there are options you can log them by adding code to the Session_End in your Global.asax file also there is a 3rd party dll that's free where you can do all of this easier and faster using `ITextSharp`

Comment: Like DavidG said, Office Automation is for client apps only.  It shouldn't even be installed on a server let alone used in a web application.